# Python look for several specific words in strong

Tags: python-3.x

So I found that it seems fairly straight foward to look for an exact match of a word in an array, say with the following:

```
color_list = ["red", "blue", "green"]
message = "blue"
y = any(x in message for x in color_list)
print y
>>> True
```

However, when I am looking for not an exact match, say, its written as capitalized, I am able to filter this out with

```
filter = message.lower()
```

But when the message becomes something like "blue!", "_red", "blueberry" or even a full sentence "i like blue!" I'm not able to filter that out in any way I have found in one function. I have found a work around, by combining several for functions, but it feels a bit bulky and will cycle through them all, and I do not know how to stop it.

```
    if data.msg == 'e80fc66b':
        filtered = list(data.user_input.lower().split())
        r = re.compile('.*red.*')
        for match in [line for line in filtered if r.match(line)]:
            print("RED")
        r = re.compile('.*orange.*')
        for match in [line for line in filtered if r.match(line)]:
            print("ORANGE")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you combine your regex expressions? e.g. .`*red.*|.*orange.*|.*blue.*`

Comment: I would like to be able to take the hit and use it in a different command. If I expand the regex I will not know which one hit.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little tip:

```
n = input()
color_list = ["red", "blue", "green"]

for i in range(len(color_list)):
    if color_list[i] in n:
        print(f"Contains {color_list[i]}")
        break
```

That would be my way to do it, if you have any questions how this works, please add a comment to my answer.
Edit:
It now stops after finding one

Comment: I like this, it's much more elegant. How am I able to stop the if as soon as one has been found?